# TSQL query to extract a value between to char where a specific set of characters is there

Tags: t-sql, substring

I have a problem I can't seem to figure out. I am trying to extract capacity from a product description. It is always between two values, "," and "oz." however there could be other commas included in the description that are not part of what I'm trying to extract. Example value is , 15 oz., or , 2 oz.,

I'm trying to find values that have the oz in them and are between two commas and I have been completely unsuccessfully. I've tried many things, but here is the latest that I have tried today and I'm just getting an error.

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    FullDescription, 
    CHARINDEX(',', FullDescription), 
    CHARINDEX('oz.',FullDescription) 
    - CHARINDEX(',', FullDescription) 
    + Len('oz.')
)
from CatalogManagement.Product
```

Comment: I should add that not all values will have a capacity so if there is no oz, it shouldn't be part of the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since the backwards pattern ,.zo is more recognisable, I'd go with the `REVERSE` function

Sample values:

"something, something more, 18oz., complete"
"shorter, 12oz., remainder"
"there is no capacity, in this, value"
"a bit more, 14oz, and some followups, maybe"

```
SELECT  REVERSE(
            SUBSTRING   (
                REVERSE(FullDescription), 
                CHARINDEX(',.zo', REVERSE(FullDescription)) + 1, 
                CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(FullDescription), CHARINDEX(',.zo', REVERSE(FullDescription)) + 1) - CHARINDEX(',.zo', REVERSE(FullDescription)) - 1
            )
        )
FROM CatalogManagement.Product
WHERE FullDescription LIKE '%oz.,%'
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting "Invalid Length Parameter Passed to the LEFT or Substring function" I think I'm running into instances where oz isn't present and its killing the query

Comment: Did you include the WHERE clause to filter out those rows where there is no oz., ?  Otherwise, can you post some sample data that includes a row where you get the error?

Comment: My sample data has a row where there is no oz value and it worked OK for me

Answer (score 0):

You might use XML-splitting together with a XQuery predicate:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Here is one with an amount, 1 oz., some more text')
                      ,('Here is one with no amount, some more text')
                      ,('a, 10 oz.')
                      ,('b, 20oz., no blank between oz and the number')
                      ,('30oz., starts with the pattern, no leading comma');

SELECT t.*
      ,A.oz.value('.','nvarchar(max)') oz
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT t.YourString AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
                       .query('/x[contains(text()[1],"oz.")]')) A(oz);
```

The idea in short:

- We use some string methods to replace commas with XML tags and to cast your string to XML. each fragment is placed within a decent `<x>` element.
- We use a predicate to return just the fragments containing "oz.".

You can filter easily with

```
WHERE LEN(A.oz.value('.','nvarchar(max)'))>0
```