# Extract Value between two specific varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to extract numeric value from a `varchar` in SQL Server 2014

`XXXX 0.5Kg` I want to return 0.5
`XXX 25YY 1.25Kg` I want to return 1.25

I want the number between last space from left and `Kg`

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769696/tsql-query-to-extract-a-value-between-to-char-where-a-specific-set-of-characters/65770066#65770066

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
select replace(right(str, charindex(' ',reverse(str))),'Kg','')
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @string as VARCHAR(MAX) = 'XXX 25YY 1.25Kg'

DECLARE @string_ as VARCHAR(MAX)  = 'XXXX 0.5Kg'

SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(@string, CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@string))),'Kg','')

SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(@string_, CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@string_))),'Kg','')
```

First find out the first space in the reverse order of the string and then break the string from that space. the replace the 'kg' from '' to obtain the value that you need. Test the result with many strings. You can use RIGHT string function in SQL to get the specific part from the string.

Comment: verbal explanations are often helpful

Comment: sure. you want me to explain the solution verbally as well?